# When rebuild is needed?

Tags: visual-studio, build, rebuild

I am working on huge existing project (Visual Studio solution contains 22 projects, mixture of C and C++ code). To "Rebuild Solution" it takes a lot of time. I would like to clearly understand what are the possible reasons to use rebuild.

When I need to use "Rebuild Solution"? 
Can someone give any example?

Comment: It's really unclear what is your question about. Usually you shouldn't do the full rebuild unless it's required by some specific reason.

Comment: Yes. I need to know all possible "specific reasons".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the super-professional answer, but in my daily work with Visual Studio I usually just do regular "builds". Except when I recognize that e.g. intellisense goes mad (or similar weird things), I usually try to do a "Clean"-"Rebuild" (in theory Rebuild should be Clean->Build, but turned out that it isn't) to get everything running again. I assume that it sometimes is necessary because of wrong caching states in VS.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. My question could be also "when to use clean". I have realized this later. It seems, there cannot be universal answer to my question(s). But any hint like yours is welcome.